# Remove Facebook sdk got error

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, linker-errors

when Remove Facebook sdk I got error like that (Due to parse sdk already in my project):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)   "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)   "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answere from myself,
Reason:-this is due to exist parse sdk solution:- You should go to built setting ->other linker flag remove -all_load and -ObjC